# Power Bi - Convert text format 11,11 in decimal number

Tags: powerbi, type-conversion

I am a newbie on PowerBi, and one of the first step I am trying to do is the data cleaning in the Power Query Editor. I have columns with number in a text format such as '58.67'. I cannot convert it to decimal directly (I have an error) so I decided to change the point by a coma such as '58,67'. After that when I convert it to decimal number format, I am having 5867 instead of 58,67.

Does somebody know how I could correct my mistake ?

Thanks in advance for your time

Comment: can you add a screenshot of the column when the number is a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In PowerQuery click on the Type conversion Icon on the left side of
   the column header.
2. From the dropdown select *Using Locale ..*
3. Set the *Data Type* to *Decimal Number*
4. Set the L*ocale* to e.g. *German (Germany)*
   Below you see sample input values having a comma as decimal separator,
   like you have
5. Click *OK* and you're done

If you don't want to repeat that with every column, go to *File - Options - Current File - Regional Setting - Locale for import*. However, this has to be done prior to the first import.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can check your window date time number setting or power bi option locale setting

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Left-click on the heading of the column you want to convert from text to decimal.
Click on the icon indicating the data type.
Then instead of clicking on "1.2 Decimal value" click on the last item "Using Locale..." 
From the Data Type drop-down list select "Decimal Number". From the Locale drop-down list select  "English (United States)".
Only this locale works, the outers do not.